Is it OK to call functions on an object created from a factory before setting it as state? Or should I wait until the re-render?
I have a component where I won't know what instance of an object to use until the user clicks a button. I then want to use that new object to initiate some action. Other components will use this object after it's created as well, so I am using a context to store it. I am wondering which of these methods is ideal, or if there is another method approach I should be considering.
const Component = () => {
  const {factory} = useFactory()
  const {globalValue, setGlobalValue} = useGlobalContext()
  <button onClick={() => {
      const concreteType = factory('type1')
      concreteType.executeSomeFunction()
      setGlobalValue(concreteType)
  }}></button>
   <button onClick={() => {
      const concreteType = factory('type2')
      concreteType.executeSomeFunction()
      setGlobalValue(concreteType)
  }}></button>
}

or should I use an effect to set the global state and wait for the next render?
const Component = () => {
  const {factory} = useFactory()
  const {globalValue, setGlobalValue} = useGlobalContext()

  useEffect(() => {
    globalValue.executeSomeFunction()
  }, [globalValue])

  <button onClick={() => {
      const concreteType = factory('type1')
      setGlobalValue(concreteType)
  }}>
}


If some other component updates globalValue, the second example will trigger the method multiple times
